# scala: create map with keys from map.keys

Tags: scala, hashmap

I have a map, let's say:

```
m1:Map[String, Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4)
```

and i now want to create a second map which has the same keys as the existing map and takes 0 as value for each key. So it should look like this:

```
m2:Map[String, Int] = Map(a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 0)
```

I tried a for loop inside the map definition, but it didn't really work. How can I do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To create a new map consider

```
m1.keys.map(k => (k,0)).toMap
```

and using a for comprehension,

```
for ( (k,v) <- m1 ) yield k -> 0
```

The approaches above create a new map. This is in contrast with the use of `mapValues` which creates a view to the original map and keeps the transformation function which is applied to the original map whenever queried. As far as the transformation function is referentially transparent, namely that it is not dependent on a context, this approach is sound. However, when a context the transformation function refers to, changes, the output from querying to the original map may also change. This is prevented with creating a new, transformed map.

Answer (score 2):

You could just `mapValues`:

```
 val m2 = m1.mapValues((v) -> 0)
```

EDIT: do read @elm's answer about the reference implications